# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local transaction already has 1 non-XA Resource: cannot add more resources

Tags: java, postgresql, glassfish, payara

me lanza esa excepcion cuando voy a agregar datos en una tabla(ArchivosCargados) en postgreSQL. probe en otros metodos de insercion de datos pero el error solo ocurre especificamente en ese metodo, segui investigando se debe a que debo cambiar la transaccion de mi pool a distribuida, pero no se como hacerlo en payara...ayuda

este es mi log

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local transaction already has 1 non-XA Resource: cannot add more resources.  
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistResource(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:364)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.rm.SystemResourceManagerImpl.enlistResource(SystemResourceManagerImpl.java:103)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:211)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:115)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:346)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:309)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.reconnect(DatasourceAccessor.java:581)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.reconnect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1634)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.incrementCallCount(DatasourceAccessor.java:321)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:615)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.executeBatch(ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.java:149)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.executeBatchedStatements(ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.java:134)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:610)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2056)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:306)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:281)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeNonCursor(DataReadQuery.java:197)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataReadQuery.java:152)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.execute(DataReadQuery.java:137)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3271)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1790)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.QuerySequence.select(QuerySequence.java:309)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.QuerySequence.updateAndSelectSequence(QuerySequence.java:254)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.StandardSequence.getGeneratedValue(StandardSequence.java:61)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.Sequence.getGeneratedValue(Sequence.java:225)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager$NoPreallocation_State.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:696)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:1107)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.ClientSessionSequencing.getNextValue(ClientSessionSequencing.java:70)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:362)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:335)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.updateObjectAndRowWithSequenceNumber(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:859)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:386)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:803)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1790)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:227)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:126)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4264)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1587)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:455)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:874)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.flush(EntityManagerWrapper.java:437)
at com.em.brayan.persistencia.EntityManagerPersistence.update(EntityManagerPersistence.java:436)
at com.em.brayan.cuentas.rips.dao.RipsDAO.actualizarArchivosCargados(RipsDAO.java:518)
at com.em.brayan.cuentas.rips.ejb.RipsFacade.actualizarArchivosCargados(RipsFacade.java:1930)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4756)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor123.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4728)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4716)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy347.actualizarArchivosCargados(Unknown Source)
at com.em.brayan.cuentas.rips.ejb.__EJB31_Generated__RipsFacade__Intf____Bean__.actualizarArchivosCargados(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:433)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
at com.em.brayan.cuentas.rips.ejb.RipsFacade$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.actualizarArchivosCargados(Unknown Source)
at com.em.brayan.cuentas.jobs.CargarAutorizacionesFacade.cargarArchivoAutorizacion(CargarAutorizacionesFacade.java:168)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4756)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor123.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4728)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4716)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy336.cargarArchivoAutorizacion(Unknown Source)
at com.em.brayan.cuentas.jobs.__EJB31_Generated__CargarAutorizacionesFacade__Intf____Bean__.cargarArchivoAutorizacion(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:433)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
at com.em.brayan.cuentas.jobs.CargarAutorizacionesFacade$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.cargarArchivoAutorizacion(Unknown Source)
at com.em.brayan.cuentas.jobs.CargarAutorizacionesFacadeSchedule.timer(CargarAutorizacionesFacadeSchedule.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4756)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundTimeout(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4728)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4716)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:3994)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1228)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$000(EJBTimerService.java:93)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:1963)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

Es por la forma en la que utilizas los recursos.
En el pool de conexiones que vas a utilizar se debe habilitar la opción "Permitir conexiones no transaccionales"(Non Transactional Connections).

Espero que sirva de algo